# Build a website with bilingual content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

​I am building a website that supports two languages (Arabic & English). I have built the website with the English content,of course I have a button to switch the language, but till now I could not find a solution to switch between languages, and alignment , you know that English is left-aligned and Arabic is right-aligned.
So, could anyone please guide me?! I have to pinpoint that I am using php for the back-end.
And please don't suggest the static design for each languages becausr this website would grow in the future

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=html+css+bi+directional+content

Answer (score 0):

[i18n/l10n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) is a really big subject... Your best bet is to use a cms, where all the different aspects of the matter have been thought of and implemented.

Nevertheless, since you are using php, I think [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) is a good place to start, at least concerning your translations.